# Session reset on opening new href link

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I have a server up and running. The session seems to reset when I click on a href link and open a new page within the same domain.

page1.php @ https://www.example.com/Modules/Page/page1.php

```
session_start();

include '../../includes/header.php';
$_SESSION['admintype'] = "Super Admin";
echo '<a href="'.HOME_URL.'/Modules/Order/orderDetails.php?ID='.$row['ID'].'">'."Click ME".'</a>';
```

Within the header.php it called session_start() again.

And here's the orderDetails.php

```
session_start();
include '../../includes/header.php';
echo $_SESSION['admintype'];
```

I do debugging by checking the session id but I got two different session id and of course the session variable I set is gone.

- I checked the session file in server, I don't think this is the reason.
- HOME_URL is https://www.example.com it's pointing to same domain.

I have no idea why it would initiate a new session instead of resume the old one. I look up question that posted by others by none of them is really helping.

Thanks in advance.

***UPDATE** : I think I found the reason behind this. There's actually two session established for every user.

I recently patched the server with a newer version and I suspect the session from previous version persist and cause the problem.

I also have another test server up which share the exact code with the production server. The link works perfectly fine over the test server which only have one session instead of two.

***UPDATE 2** : The problem was due to there's actually two session for "mysite.com" and "www.mysite.com". I guess there's some conflict between the cookie session when the redirect takes place. It send out the cookie session that was no longer valid and that's why the session variable is being unset.

Comment: did you set your session variables in the initial session?

Comment: do you have cookies enabled in your browser and are you seeing your session cookie set?

Comment: Yes I did, the session variables works fine until I open up a new page through href link. Actually it's not just the session variable is gone but the entire session has been reset and a brand new session is initiated instead.

Comment: Maybe your session timeout on inactivity is set low. By default its 30 minutes. So if the page sits for 30 mins before you click the next link that happens. If you've changed it to be lower...

Comment: there must be something missing in your sample code.  can you edit it to show more code (starting from the top).  Also are you possibly killing the session at the end of the page?

Comment: No I checked all scripts that included and no one is killing the session. However I found a white space before <?php. I removed it but still the session is being reset some how.

Comment: I don't think the problem is due to inactivity though. I tried to start a fresh new session and still the session was reset after opening the href link.

Comment: Sorry. the problem was due to the missing 'www' in the redirecting URL.